# Validate a renaming pattern with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to validate a pattern used for renaming.
The user will fill value like :

```
%1% - %3%%2%
```

I'm able to match with a regex, everything is ok:

```
[^%]*(%[\d]+%)+[^%]*
```

But before that I want to validate the string and be able to find when the user made mistakes like :

```
%1% - %3%2%
%1% - %3%%2
...
```

Whatever I try, I can get the corrected value but I don't know if the string is well formatted or not. Only to check manually.
Are there any way with regex to answer to this problem ? Or maybe I don't need regex for this...

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

For a good example, just take a program which rename your mp3 files.
You define a mapping between %1% and the track title, %2% for the artist, ...

Sorry, my mistake was to provide only one string. But the user can submit :

```
%1% - %3%%2%
%1%_%2%%3%
%1%%3% %2%
...
```

Whatever he want. My goal to parse the string if everything is correct, seems ok for me. Unless I find a tricky bad example.
But before I save it, I want to validate and refuse a string like

```
%1% - %3%%2
```

My problem was to find the wrong value. What I done, and seems to me *not clean*, is to use my regex, and then verify if the total of "%" found in the string is even and if this total divided by 2 is equal of the total of group found. But I'm not sure it works always (not sure if my last phrase is clear)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your regular expression either matches (i.e. the string is a well-formatted replacement pattern) or it doesn't match (string is not a well-formatted replacement pattern). Where is the problem?

Comment: `if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\A%[0-9]+% - %[0-9]+%%[0-9]+%\z")) {return true;}`

Comment: If you have find/replace at your disposal, I'd match the correct lines (including newline chars) and replace them with empty string. That way you'll get all the wrong lines. If you want to do this all in RE is might be a little more tricky...

Comment: OK, my question miss some precisions. I'd updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex is what you're trying to accomplish.

```
(%[\d]%) - (%[\d]%)*
```

Comment: OP wants the lines that do not conform to the expression, not the ones that do.

Comment: @Izzy, but the lines that do not conform are simply the ones that don't match the above pattern.

Comment: Now I'm a little confused too. I think my expression is what he wants, but now I'm wondering if he only wanted two %[/d]% after the " - ". We need clarification from OP before we can continue.

Comment: The regex parser doesn't understand spaces, remove the spaces in your pattern to `\s`. Otherwise your pattern fails on his first example. Also putting `\d` in a set `[ ]` is superfluous and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if the string is well formatted or not.

This pattern puts in a check for three consecutive `%%%` which seems to catch a good number of failure bad format scenarios. Then we can require the pattern **to validate*** for only good items by adding the `$` anchor to require only fully formed valid patterns.

The valid pattern of `(%\d%)` is what we seek:

```
^         # Start Anchor
(?!.+%%%) # Stop if 3 % anywhere.
%\d%      # First \d
\s-\s     # Dash and spaces
(%\d%)+   # Groups of numbers
$         # Stop Anchor
```

It works on the one example you gave `%1% - %3%%2%` and doesn't match on the 2 failure examples you provided.

Because this pattern is documented you will need to use `IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` as a regex option. Otherwise delete all comments and join onto one line without spaces.

---

When one uses `*` (zero to many) it can create some ungodly backtracking scenarios which can actually fail a good pattern. Is there really going to be **zero** items?

Your examples don't show it; if not why not use `+` 1 to many?